# Modify ChartSpace axis min max

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am attempting to set the X and Y axes bounds of a ChartSpace chart to the width of my data. However, the following code does not work;

```
With ChartControl
    .DataSource = SpdShtCtrl
    With .Charts.Add
        .Type = chChartTypeScatterLine

        With .Axes(chCategoryAxis)
            .Left = WorksheetFunction.Min(SpdShtCtrl.Range("XValues"))
            .Right = WorksheetFunction.Max(SpdShtCtrl.Range("XValues"))
        End With

        With .Axes(chValueAxis)
            .Bottom = WorksheetFunction.Min(SpdShtCtrl.Range("YValues"))
            .Top = WorksheetFunction.Max(SpdShtCtrl.Range("YValues"))
        End With

        '...

    End With
End With
```

The `.Right` method fails with the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment." which I understand because, on inspection, the `.Right` and `.Bottom` properties are read only, whereas the `.Left` and `.Top` properties are read/write. However, I don't understand why this should be the case.

Commenting out the `.Right` and `.Bottom` calls compiles fine, but I get a runtime error on calling the `.Left` method that says "This is an inappropriate time to alter layout."

What is the correct way to set X and Y axes bounds for a ChartSpace chart? I can't seem to find information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Wrong Approach

It turns out that I was barking up the wrong tree. Setting the `.Left` property moves the axis on the screen, not changing the minimum data value that is plotted! In case anyone is wondering, I have included the correct usage of the `.Left` property.

I found out the answer with a combination of [Left property help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa206393%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [AfterLayout event help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa193067%28v=office.11%29.aspx). It involves setting the following property on the `ChartSpace`

```
.AllowLayoutEvents = True
```

And creating an event handler for the `AfterLayout` event on the `ChartSpace`;

```
Private Sub ChartControl_AfterLayout(ByVal drawObject As OWC11.ChChartDraw)
    ChartControl.Charts(0).Axes(chCategoryAxis).Left = _
        WorksheetFunction.Min(SpdShtCtrl.Range("XValues"))
End Sub
```

### Working Method

What I really wanted to do was to set the `.Scalings` property on the series, i.e.

```
With ChartControl.SeriesCollection(0)
    .Scalings(chDimXValues).Minimum = bla
    .Scalings(chDimXValues).Maximum = bla
    .Scalings(chDimYValues).Minimum = bla
    .Scalings(chDimYValues).Maximum = bla
End With
```